# max channel limit and max subscription limit

Tags: redis

I am trying to use Redis pub sub for managing websockets from a client chat app.

Every unique user creates a channel for every user called uuid_channel. So i will have thousands of channels created which a group of servers are listening to which has websocket connection open to clients.

When messages are published to these channels in redis, subscribers on a particular server will get the notification and send it back via websocket.

Is it ok to do this use case with Redis pub sub?